# What changes are needed to switch database from SQL Server to Oracle using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework

I have developed a MVC web application using Entity Framework with SQL Server as backend. I have used a database-first approach.

Now my client wants to switch to an Oracle database. I am in the process of doing impact analysis of switching from SQL Server to Oracle database. My client believes that it is as simple as changing connection string.

My question is, considering the fact that the table name, table structure, relationships and attributes are all same with SQL Server database, what changes do I need to do in my project to switch from MS SQL to Oracle?

Do I need to create a new `edmx` file for Oracle database or do I only need to change the connection string and use the same context?

Also if in future this needs to be reversed, then is there a good practice or solution to support both the databases?

Thank you.

Comment: Speaking as one who works on a project that did this, my best advice is you shoot whoever wants to use Oracle and hide their body.  Or, you're going to have to get an Oracle implementation of ado.net (we used devart), and spend all of your time hacking around tons of corner cases.  For example, we had to create a framework to do a lot of the scut work generically.  Scut work being the tweaks that have to be done to a database in order to make it fast, all of which are unique to each type of RDBMS...

Comment: How will the oracle database be constructed? Which oracle version are we talking about? I'm developing Code First against an oracle database and there are some tweaks. I believe it would become a nightmare with a transfer from existing MS SQL database if the amount of tables is not trivial.

Comment: IF your client provides you with a finished DB, where database first generates a compatible model for your existing code, it should really be as trivial as switching the connection string. But be aware if they want you to be the one who builds that 'compatible' database.

Comment: You'll probably run into problems with identifier names (table names, column names, etc...) where in SQL Server the typical setup will do a case insensitive check, but in Oracle it will be case sensitive. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks Will, grek40 and @sstan for the comment. However I am still clueless as to how to proceed. Shall I delete my existing edmx and create a new one? or do I just need to change the connection string and expect everything to fall in place?  (I want to use the Oracle 11g and the number of tables are less.)

Comment: Just to spell out one example of potential problems: Oracle 11g comes without `IDENTITY` columns, so if there are any in the MS SQL database, a trigger-based workaround or manual ID assignment is needed. This is just one little point in a larger list but it should show the importance of the question "how is the oracle db created and who is responsible for it?". If the database transfer is done 100% correctly, don't throw away your model, just change the connection string and start testing... most likely you will be far away from 100%

Answer (score 0):

oracle has a 30 character limit for item (table, index, column) so if you are verbose in any of your naming you are going to have to rename a bunch of items.

i don't like using an edmx.  it might be easier with code first models.

Comment: I am not using verbose. You suggest to implement code first, so do I need to create all the entities again and delete the existing one?